# Javascript replace() misbehaves on iPhone for long strings

Tags: javascript, iphone, regex, string, replace

I can't seem to explain this the proper way, but `String.prototype.replace()` acts differently on an iPhone vs. PC if an attribute's value is too long (both Chrome and Safari).

I have a simple function that replaces any `{}` encapsulation with the matching substring which should be the key of a passed object:

```
const data = { lang: "en", version: "1.0", user: "marc" };
const rep = (html, data) =>
    html.replace(/\{*([\w_\-]+)*\}/g, (match, capture) => data[capture] || "");

const html = '<input type="hidden" name="abcdefghijklmnopqr" value="{lang}">'
```

The code above only works on the iPhone only if the name attribute is short. Returning:

`<input type="hidden" name="abc" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="abcdefghijklmnopqr" value="{lang}">`

You can checkout the demo with your iPhone here:
https://codepen.io/raduchiriac/pen/wQVvRv?editors=0010

EDIT: After receiving the answer below I fixed it using `{([\w_\-]+)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\{*([\w_\-]+)*\}
  ^
  |
```

This asterisk in your pattern causes [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Most probably, the engine just stops matching to avoid a crash after some amount of steps. ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BM46Cr/1) gave up after 75,000).

Comment: It's the first time I hear about something like this. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Any idea why changing the flavor on regex101 to javascript, we don't get the `catastrophic backtracking` anymore

Comment: @RaduChiriac: CB is tricky to detect, I assume regex101 shows the badge when it reaches  a certain limit of steps. A message like "1 match 98567 steps" is basically the same as CB...